# Exception occurred while running openmeeting-web

Tags: java, red5, openmeetings

I have taken checkout of latest code of openmeetings from their GitHub mirror repository. While running openmeeting-web, I am getting following exception.

```
 INFO 08-14 13:03:54.013 33 81 ROOT [0.0-startStop-1] - Starting up context:openmeetings-web
Filter init: openmeetings-web
Aug 14, 2017 1:03:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [OpenmeetingsApplication]
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:418)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.<clinit>(WicketFilter.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I understood the exception is coming due to multiple slf4j jars. But I am not getting the exact solution to solve this error. Please help.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "While running openmeeting-web"? you should run openmeetings-server... could you please provide more details on this?

Comment: I ran openmeeting-web project on red5 server directly. I am new to this am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are building from sources you most probably need `unpacked` build as described here:
http://openmeetings.apache.org/BuildInstructions.html#Tips_and_Gotchas

then perform

`cd openmeetings-server/target/server
./red5-debug.sh`

Comment: I have tried building source with unpacked build, still same exception I am getting.

Comment: OpenMeetings doesn't provides such output on start ... Please perform the exact steps I have provided in my answer

Comment: okay this steps will start the red5 server. Can you point me to link where I can find proper guidance to do modifications in openmeetings source code, build it and publish it on localhost. 
I have worked with red5 but with openmeeting I am getting confused. So if I am getting proper direction that will be helpful.